# Regular expression to remove unwanted characters from the String

Tags: java, regex, string, string-utils

I have a requirement where I need to remove unwanted characters for String in java.
For example,
Input String is

```
Income ......................4,456
liability........................56,445.99
```

I want the output as

```
Income 4,456
liability 56,445.99
```

What is the best approach to write this in java. I am parsing large documents
for this hence it should be performance optimized.

Comment: What have you tried? Also, are they always one word then white space then a number?

Comment: You're adding a character to the second line.

Comment: As I mentioned , I am trying to read a document. So the oreder could be random. I am basically cleaning up the extra special characters like "." and keeping only meaningful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this replace with this line of code:

```
System.out.println("asdfadf ..........34,4234.34".replaceAll("[ ]*\\.{2,}"," "));
```

Comment: hat exactly is this regular expression doing? I mean I need to understand how exactly is working.

Comment: [ ]* Search for 0 to * whit spaces -- \\.{2,} search for 2 to * dot.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example, I might use the following replacement:

```
String input = "Income ......................4,456";
input = input.replaceAll("(\\w+)\\s*\\.+(.*)", "$1 $2");
System.out.println(input);
```

Here is an explanation of the pattern being used:

```
(\\w+)   match AND capture one or more word characters
\\s*     match zero or more whitespace characters
\\.+     match one or more literal dots
(.*)     match AND capture the rest of the line
```

The two quantities in parentheses are known as *capture groups*.  The regex engine remembers what these were while matching, and makes them available, in order, as `$1` and `$2` to use in the replacement string.

**Output:**

```
Income 4,456
```

## Demo

Comment: What exactly is this regular expression doing? I mean I need to understand how exactly is working.

Comment: The expression worked for the example i illustrated. However, I ran into another String as shown below Fire........................ ..................................   ...........598,368..............598,368......

Comment: Update your question and show us data covering _every_ edge case.  Going back and forth like this with everyone isn't going to get you anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do that is like:

```
String result = yourString.replaceAll("[-+.^:,]","");
```

That will replace this special character with nothing.

Comment: Your solution has a problem, namely that it would also strip the punctuation from the numbers on the right side of each line.

Comment: It also replaces the decimal point in the second value (the one just before `99`), which is not desired.

Comment: I agree, this is not right solution. I thaught about it the same way. Let me try other solutions mentioned above. Thanks for prompt responses.